# Prometheus multiple instances of microservices

Tags: service, prometheus

I am wondering how Prometheus behaves, if there are multiple instances of a service available.
For example there is one service which is deployed in a kubernetes cluster with three instances running.

Each instance increases its count-metric.

What happens when prometheus scrapes these instances and receives the three values?

Does prometheus sum them up?
Does the last of the three values to be scraped override the first two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus will ingest the three values from the three targets, which (unless you've done something very weird) will then exist independently.

No math will be performed on them other than math you request in PromQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can sum the values of multiple instances.
If you set a rule, you can sum by application.
An example for an alert, would be:

```
groups:
  - name: default
    rules:
      - alert: defaultAlert
        expr:  sum by (application) (expression_that_you_want)
```

The relevant thing here is the: `sum by (application)`

You can sum by others labels as well.